# insert new rows to pandas dataframe every month without overwriting actual data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame like this one:

```
data = {'ID':["AB2343","CD4565"],
        'StartDate':["01/01/2020","01/01/2021"],
        'EndDate':["31/12/2021","31/12/2022"],
        'AgreedMonthlyBilling':[1500,4500],
        'ActualMonthlyBilling':[1200,3000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

ID, StartDate, EndDate and AgreedMonthlyBilling do not change after I insert the respective values (i.e. 1500 and 4500 in AgreedMonthlyBilling stays forever) The last one(ActualMonthlyBilling which is modified manually in an excel sheet), changes every month(i.e. January has 1200 and 3000, February has 0 and 1500, March has 3000 and 1000).
What I want to do is to add a new row every new month until EndDates (this means that, i.e. we are at 01/03/2022, I'll only have 3 months from 2022 added), and only when a new month arrives, not before (this is where I'm stuck). I have the following:

```
repeats = (pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate']) - pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])) // np.timedelta64(1, 'M') + 1
periods = np.concatenate([pd.period_range(start=pd.to_datetime(d), periods=r, freq='M')
                          for d, r in zip(df['StartDate'], repeats)])
    
new_df = (pd.DataFrame(
            np.repeat(df.values, repeats, 0),
            columns=df.columns,
            index=periods)
            .assign(Month = [x.month for x in periods],
                    Year = [x.year for x in periods]))
```

What I'm getting with this is a new DataFrame with the complete months between StartDate and EndDate, but everytime I change the ActualMonthlyBilling, I overwrite the past data in ActualMonthlyBilling, and I'm not keeping the old records that I want to keep track of.

This is what I'm getting

| ID | Month | Year | ExpectedBilling | RealBilling |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB2343 | 01 | 2020 | 1500 | 1350 overwritted |
| AB2343 | 02 | 2020 | 1500 | 1350 overwritted |
| AB2343 | 03 | 2020 | 1500 | 1350 overwritted |

Edit: The expected outcome is the following:

| ID | Month | Year | ExpectedBilling | RealBilling |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB2343 | 01 | 2020 | 1500 | 1290 (first) |
| AB2343 | 02 | 2020 | 1500 | 1350(second insert) |
| AB2343 | 03 | 2020 | 1500 | 300 (third insert) |

What I want is to add a new row every month whenever I made the changes in ActualMonthlyBilling, which I do monthly. I've been doing this manually and its terribly painful (1000+ rows).
i.e. If we are in January and the column "ActualMonthlyBilling" points to 1290, I want to add the row correspondant to January with its ID, Month, Year and ExpectedBilling (that do not change) and the RealBilling(which changes every month) this should be pointed in the First parenthesis in the table. If we move then to February, in the original database the 1290 changes to 1350, so there should be a second insert with the 1350 (second parenthesis) and so on.

Thanks in Advance to everyone.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: Please minimize your example and explicity describe what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Suppose you have this current dataframe:

```
       ID  Month  Year  ExpectedBilling  RealBilling
0  AB2343      1  2022             1500         1290
1  AB2343      2  2022             1500         1350
2  CD4565      1  2022             4500         3000
3  CD4565      2  2022             4500         3250
```

You want to append a new row for March 2022 per ID:

```
new_df = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False) \
           .agg({'ID': 'first', 'ExpectedBilling': 'last'}) \
           .assign(Month=today.month, Year=today.year)

out = pd.concat([df, new_df]).sort_values(['ID', 'Month', 'Year'], ignore_index=True)
print(out)

# Output
       ID  Month  Year  ExpectedBilling  RealBilling
0  AB2343      1  2022             1500       1290.0
1  AB2343      2  2022             1500       1350.0
2  AB2343      3  2022             1500          NaN
3  CD4565      1  2022             4500       3000.0
4  CD4565      2  2022             4500       3250.0
5  CD4565      3  2022             4500          NaN
```

The question is how do you insert a new value for `RealBilling` column?

---

**Old answer**

```
today = pd.Timestamp.today()
period = df.apply(lambda x: pd.period_range(x['StartDate'], today, freq='M'), axis=1)

new_df = df.assign(Period=period).explode('Period').set_index('Period') \
           .assign(Month=lambda x: x.index.month, Year=lambda x: x.index.year)
```

Output:

```
             ID   StartDate     EndDate  AgreedMonthlyPrice  ActualMonthlyPrice  Month  Year
Period                                                                                      
2020-01  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      1  2020
2020-02  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      2  2020
2020-03  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      3  2020
2020-04  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      4  2020
2020-05  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      5  2020
2020-06  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      6  2020
2020-07  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      7  2020
2020-08  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      8  2020
2020-09  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      9  2020
2020-10  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290     10  2020
2020-11  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290     11  2020
2020-12  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290     12  2020
2021-01  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      1  2021
2021-02  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      2  2021
2021-03  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      3  2021
2021-04  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      4  2021
2021-05  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      5  2021
2021-06  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      6  2021
2021-07  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      7  2021
2021-08  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      8  2021
2021-09  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      9  2021
2021-10  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290     10  2021
2021-11  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290     11  2021
2021-12  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290     12  2021
2022-01  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      1  2022
2022-02  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      2  2022
2022-03  AB2343  01/01/2020  31/12/2022                1500                1290      3  2022
2021-01  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      1  2021
2021-02  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      2  2021
2021-03  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      3  2021
2021-04  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      4  2021
2021-05  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      5  2021
2021-06  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      6  2021
2021-07  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      7  2021
2021-08  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      8  2021
2021-09  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      9  2021
2021-10  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000     10  2021
2021-11  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000     11  2021
2021-12  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000     12  2021
2022-01  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      1  2022
2022-02  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      2  2022
2022-03  CD4565  01/01/2021  31/12/2025                4500                3000      3  2022
```

Comment: This does a great thing, but I think I'm not being clear enough about my problem (sorry about that). What I want to do is to add one single row every month without overwriting the past billings. When I execute this, I overwrite all the past billings. Is there a way to do this? I mean, to keep i.e. 1290 in march but in april there is a change in the actual billing or price (i.e.) like 1500, there should be 1290 in march and 1500 in april, can you see where im going? Please let me know

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't understand the real usefulness of your first dataframe at the top of your post. Can you check my update, please?

Comment: Simplifying what I want, is to insert rows from a dataframe into a new one, without overwriting all the previous data (My problem resides in that my code is building the complete dataframe, not inserting the data). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you start from your dataframe at the top of your post, I don't know how to do that. You should have an intermediate dataframe. Where is your dataframe from February?

Comment: Hmmm I see... I'll try with an intermediate dataframe and look out if it works.
Thanks!

Comment: Where do you currently store the `RealBilling` for January and February and all previous months?